# Composite key in ERD for Database design

Tags: foreign-keys, key, composite, erd

Can we show composite key Nomination_ID with ( one attribute and two foreign keys) in ER diagram?I have a table(Entity) called Nomination. It has following : Nom_ID(PK), Award_ID(FK), URL_ID(FK) and and Year(Attribute) Combining two FKeys and Year Attribute makes the row unique. I want to show it on ER Diagram. How would I represent this on Diagram? Do I need to draw PK Attribute and three attributes coming out of it or draw all of them separately connecting to the Table?

Answer (score 1):

`Nomination_ID` means nothing to us on Stack Overflow.

You seem to not understand the definition of a composite key, which is a combination of two or more fields that uniquely identify a row. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key). Has nothing to do with [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

Comment: @Beyg Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather then as comments.